Sollte W-IdNr. eher mit oder ohne Punkt geschrieben werden?
Nach §82 des amtlichen Regelwerkes werden gekürzte Wörter mit einem Abkürzungspunkt am Ende geschrieben. §82-E2 besagt jedoch, dass bestimmte Kürzungen ohne Punkt geschrieben werden (cm, km, EU), der Duden erweitert dies um "viele fachsprachliche Schreibabkürzungen" wie JuSchG (Jugendschutzgesetz),  BStMdI (Bayrisches Staatsministerium des Innern) oder OStRin (Oberstudienrätin).
Gilt die W-IdNr (Wirtschafts-Identifikationsnummer) jetzt auch als solche fachsprachliche Schreibabkürzung? Das BZSt (Bundeszentralamt für Steuern) schreibt sie auf der dazugehörigen Seite immer mit Punkt, während eine Seite weiter bei der ähnlich gelagerten USt-IdNr diese fünfmal ohne und achtmal mit Punkt auftaucht.
Gibt es nun dazu eine feste Regelung oder ist es Auslegungssache, ob es sich um eine fachsprachliche Schreibabkürzung handelt?

Den von dir zitierten Quellen nach scheint es eine Grauzone zu sein. Wie sieht eine Antwort aus, von der du dir eine Klärung erhoffst? Welche Autorität oder welche Fakten würden für dich den Ausschlag geben?

Wenn jemand schreiben würde, dass Nummer immer mit Punkt abgekürzt wird (-> Nr.), und diese Regel grundsätzlich auf mit Nr. als Suffix gebildete Schreibabkürzungen zu übertragen ist, würde mich das in der Tendenz zur Schreibweise mit Punkt bestärken.

Es gibt eine Organisation die heißt Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung.
https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/
Diese hat in 2018 ein Regelwerk angepasst, welches 2016 veröffentlicht wurde.
https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf
Dort kann man in Regel 102 lesen:

Bestimmte Abkürzungen, Kurzwörter und dergleichen stehen üblicherweise
ohne Punkt.

Weiterhin steht da:

E2: In einigen Fällen gibt es Doppelformen. Co./Co (ko) (= Companie),
M. d. B./MdB (= Mitglied des Bundestages), G.m.b.H./GmbH (=
Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung); WW/Wirk. Wort (= Wirkendes
Wort; Titel einer Zeitschrift), AA/Ausw. Amt (= Auswärtiges Amt)

Da "üblicherweise" verwendet wird und ein Teil der Regel offen zugibt, dass es akzeptierte Doppelformen gibt sollten wir "W-IdNr" bei den Initialworten und Abkürzungen im Graubereich einordnen.
Gestützt wird diese Entscheidung durch die offenkundige Uneindeutigkeit auf der Seite des BZSt.
Dementsprechend die Empfehlung:
Mache dir die Welt, wide wide wie sie dir gefällt ;)

Sehr viele Firmennamen werden ohne Punkt geschrieben: BMW, BASF, VW,
weil sie als Namen und nicht als (historisch bedingte) Abkuerzungen gelten.
Im Zusammenhang mit juristischen und Behoerdenschriften (aller
Bundesministerien usw) wird fuer Gesetzestexte und Verordnungen soweit
ich das beurteilen kann immer eine Camel-Case (Gross-Kleinschreibung)
ohne Punkt verwendet; Grund ist wahrscheinlich dass man bei Benutzung
der Punkte in den ohnehin kaum durchschaubaren Satzkonstrukten nicht
mehr Satzende  und Abkuerzungspunkte unterscheiden koennte, und die
gemischte Gross/Kleinschreibung Worte sowieso als Abkuerzungen kennzeichnet.

Ich fürchte, die Antwort wird anders ausfallen, als sich der Fragesteller vermutlich erhofft.
Zu allererst: "Sprache" ist das, was tatsächlich gesprochen und geschrieben wird. Die Vorstellung, daß ein "amtliches Regelwerk" bindende Verpflichtungen, diese oder jene sprachliche Form zu wählen, aufstellen könnte, spricht jeder linguistischen und historischen Erkenntnis Hohn. So funktioniert Sprachentwicklung nun einmal nicht!
Davon abgesehen: das "amtliche Regelwerk" ist so offensichtlich bar linguistischer Grundkenntnis verfaßt worden, daß sich die Frage stellt, ob das, was da "amtlich geregelt" wird, überhaupt irgendein Deutsch (geschweige denn ein korrektes) ist.
Es liegt mir fern, hier die Debatte neu zu eröffnen, nur pars pro toto, ein Beispiel unter unzähligen: daß man nun "(ein-)bläuen" statt "bleuen" zu schreiben hat, weil es angeblich von "blau" kommt, kann ein einziger kurzer Blick in ein etymologisches Wörterbuch entkräften: es kommt von ahd. bliuwan, das mit germanisch "*bleww-a-" ("schlagen") zusammenhängt und ist mit "Pleuel" (das man nach wie vor so und nicht "Pläuel" oder "Bläuel" schreibt) verwandt. Klar, es gibt schießlich das "Stammschreibungsprinzip" und "blau" gibt es ja - man könnte das nur irgendwann "beräuen", denn "rau" gibts auch.
Als Drittes: das sogenannte "amtliche Regelwerk" regelt - das, was Ämter zu tun haben. Dieses Regelwerk gilt verbindlich für Ämter und den Personen, die dort arbeiten und auch für diese nur für die Zeit, in der sie dort arbeiten. Was die in ihrer Freizeit so sagen und schreiben, das amtliche oder ein richtiges Deutsch, das ist ihre eigene Entscheidung.
Das Regelwerk ist außerdem bindend für Kinder, die im Geltungsbereich des Regelwerks zur Schule gehen, Studenten, die Arbeiten auf Deutsch verfassen und ähnliche Personen - aber auch nur, soweit sie mit diesen Institutionen befaßt sind. Auch Schüler, Studenten, etc. können und dürfen außerschulisch/außeruniversitär Sprache ohne Beachtung des Regelwerks verwenden ohne dafür von jemandem belangt werden zu können.
Nach diesen Einschränkungen nun zur Antwort: was das Regelwerk vorgibt und inwieweit sich irgendein Amt tatsächlich daran hält, ist eine Frage, die zwischen dem Amt und (aufgrund des angegebenen Links gehe ich von Deutschland aus) dem Kultusministerium zu klären ist. Genau genommen verstößt mindestens eine von Dir erwähnte Praxis gegen die amtliche Regelung und müßte durch das Kultusministerium gerügt bzw. die Korrektur durch dasselbe eingefordert werden. Meine Vermutung ist, daß es dort keinen (mehr) interessiert, weil man dessen Budget konsequent jedes Jahr zu Polizei und Militär weiter umverteilt.
Für Dich hat das, was auf den genannten Seiten steht, überhaupt keinen Einfluß - sprachlichen nicht und grammatikalisch normierenden schon gar nicht.
Hingegen übt - siehe den mit "zu allererst" eingeleiteten Absatz oben und um den rechtspositivistischen Jargon zu bemühen - der tatsächliche Sprachgebrauch die normierende Kraft des Faktischen aus. Richtig ist, was ein Großteil sprachlich kompetenter Muttersprachler als richtig empfindet.
Das Problem ist, daß unser Sprachzentrum nicht direkt zugänglich ist, so wie unser Verstand: wir können nachvollziehen, was wir uns denken und darüber nachdenken, was wir so denken und wie wir das tun. Allgemein nennt man diese Metaebene "Philosophie" und es ist eine noble Beschäftigung. Etwas Vergleichbares kann aber die Linguistik nicht, denn ein analoger Blick ins Sprachzentrum ist uns (und dem Verstand) verwehrt. Wir können zwar mit dem Verstand nachträglich das, was aus dem Sprachzentrum kommt, bearbeiten*), aber dem Sprachzentrum über die Schulter zu schauen, wie es zu seinen Ergebnissen kommt - das können wir nicht.
Wir können es lediglich wie eine Black Box mit allem möglichen füttern, die Resultate betrachten und daraus unsere Schlüsse ziehen.
Sehen wir uns also alles mögliche an und ziehen wir:
Es gibt Abkürzungen, bei denen uns die Verwendung eines Punkts offensichtlich unsinnig erscheint, nämlich bei Bildungen aus Initialen ("BMW", "AEG", "ABGB", "WM") und den meisten Einheiten und Quasi-Einheiten: "km", "mg", "mmol/l", ebenso "d" (dies, Tage), hingegen "Stk." (Stück), "Jhdt.".
Es gibt Abkürzungen, bei denen, obwohl sie weit verbreitet sind, dennoch ein Punkt gesetzt wird: "Nr.", "S." (Seite).
Wortteile, die offensichtlich Abkürzungen sind, werden praktisch immer mit Punkt als Abkürzungen markiert: "Abk." (Abkürzung), "Verz." (Verzeichnis), "Abb." (Abbildung), "Bed." (Bedeutung).
Im juristischen Jargon - allerdings hauptsächlich dort und in verwandten Bereichen, worunter ich Steuerangelegenheiten zähle - hat es sich eingebürgert, alle möglichen Abkürzungen ohne Punkt zu schreiben, wie eben das erwähnte "JuSchG" und das "BZSt". Das ist allerdings eine Marotte der Juristen und diesem Bereich nahestehenden Berufen (etwa Steuerberatern, Wirtschaftsprüfern, und dergleichen). Ich kenne jedenfalls keinen Chemiker, der etwa "Alkohol" "Alk." abkürzen würde ohne einen Punkt dahinterzusetzen.
Von einer generellen Regel für "fachsprachliche Schreibabkürzungen" kann also überhaupt keine Rede sein.
Tatsächlich gilt die Frage aber spezifisch einem Begriff aus dem Steuerwesen, der W-IdNr (Wirtschafts-Identifikationsnummer). Durch den faktisch geübten Jargon der Branche wäre eine Schreibung ohne Punkt durchaus gedeckt und zumindest argumentierbar korrekt. Andererseits will mein Sprachzentrum hinter einer Zusammensetzung mit "Nummer" (und möglicherweise in Analogie zu dieser) einen Punkt setzen. Ganz falsch kann der Punkt also nicht sein, auch wenn ich natürlich leicht mein Sprachzentrum - wer ist das schon - mit dem Verstand überstimmen kann. Meistens liege ich damit, nämlich mit dem Überstimmen, falsch, aber - independent observations, even though they missed the target, had an average point of impact very near the spot he aimed at +) - konstant falsch ist ja auch irgendwie richtig, oder?
Ich empfehle also, zu machen, was Du willst oder, noch besser, was Dein Sprachzentrum Dir rät, denn wie auch immer Du Dich entscheidest, ist es zumindest argumentierbar richtig und offensichtlich hat sich selbst die amtliche Regelungswut in Allgemeinplätze geflüchtet, anstatt Tacheles zu reden.

*) von dort kommen so motivierte Bildungen wie etwa "zwei Espressi" nämlich - da hat das Sprachzentrum entrüstet gequiekt und dann beleidigt den Mund gehalten, während sich der Verstand im Glanze des Bildungsbürgertums gesonnt hat, nicht ahnend, daß man in Italien tatsächlich "due caffé" bestellen würde, weil der "Espresso" keine Art Kaffee ist, sondern eine Art, Kaffee zu trinken - auf die Schnelle nämlich
+) aus: Hiawatha Designs an Experiment

Deine Antwort hat ein bisschen viel obiter dictum, oder?
